# How to use OpenACC data region for structured data?

Tags: gpu, data-transfer, openacc

I am new to OpenACC. I have a query related to structured data transfer using the `#pragma acc data` directive. According to the site https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/OpenACC_Tutorial_-_Data_movement

> *The data directive defines a region of code in which GPU arrays remain on the GPU and are shared among all kernels in that region.*

I do understand the use of `copy` clause. I was wondering whether this directive can be used without any clause?

I read the OpenACC 2.7 specification. This part is not clear if clause is **mandatory** or not. My understanding is that if a data region is defined without specifying any data explicitly, then all data used within that region will implicitly remain on the GPU throughout the data region.

```
#pragma acc data
{
    #pragma acc kernels 
    // Kernel 1

    #pragma acc kernels
    // Kernel 2
}
```

That means, for the above code, all data used in Kernel 1 and Kernel 2 will remain on the GPU for the entire duration of the data region.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are implicit data regions as part of a parallel construct (i.e. the data region that's part of a "paralllel" or "kernels" region), where the compiler will attempt to implicitly copy the data to the device assuming the size and shape of the data is known.  Otherwise, you do need to use data clauses to define the shape and size.

For the other data region constructs, structured, unstructured, and declare, you do need to have your variables that you want on the device included in a data clause, where the data clause may be copy, copyin, copyout, create, present, or deviceptr (or delete for exit data directives).  The compiler can't assume what data you want on the device, so in general won't implicitly copy it for you.

Comment: Thank You Mat for the answer. What I am looking for is there any way the compiler can implicitly decide and keep data on the GPU to be used by multiple kernels. I know I can achieve this by using copyin and coyout clause. I am thinking if it can be done implicitly. 

Thank You.

Comment: The compiler doesn't have a view over the whole program so can't really decide implicitly when and how much data to transfer.  It can for an individual compute region (if the size and shape of the data are known), but not for larger regions.  If you are using NVIDIA devices with the PGI compilers, you may consider using CUDA Unified Memory (enabled via the -ta=tesla:managed flag).  With Unified Memory, the CUDA driver will manage transfers of dynamically allocated data so you don't need to uses data regions at all.  Though static and stack data still needs to be user managed.